# Perfect Server HTTP - File not found

Tags: swift, perfect

I’m using Perfect Server to create a Swift backend for my application.

After following this tutorial: http://www.chrismanahan.com/creating-a-web-service-swift-perfect I get to the stage where I test my server.

When PerfectServerHTTP loads, I open up `http://localhost:8181/posts` but receive a print out saying `The file “/posts" was not found.`

How do I setup the server side of the project? There’s no mention of this in the tutorial.

Answer (score 2):

Stupid mistake but I’ll post for anyone else who’s unable to follow instructions like me…

The problem was the scheme selected **needs to be** your project’s scheme, **not** the PerfectServer HTTP App scheme

Comment: So please close this answer , now it's yet an open question